# Fonts are not applied to text in Lualatex

Tags: errors, luatex, fontspec, indic

I am not able to get Sanskrit characters to display in the MWE given below. Trying to process it through lualatex. Peculiarly it spits below xetex related error:

```
> hyph-sa.pat.txt Language sanskrit was not yet loaded; created with id
> 4 Language sanskrit already loaded; id is 4 Package polyglossia Info:
> Skipping automatic font setup for language sanskrit.
> 
> ! Undefined control sequence. l.53 \newXeTeXintercharclass
>                           \sanskrit@punctthin % ! ? ; : danda double_danda ?  ! Undefined control sequence. l.53
> \newXeTeXintercharclass\sanskrit@punctthin
>                                               % ! ? ; : danda double_danda ?  )
```

This is the code I am using.

```
\documentclass[9pt,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[text={4.3in,6.95in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguages{sanskrit}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Shobhika}[Script=Devanagari]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Shobhika}[Script=Devanagari,Ligatures=TeX]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hymn to Lord Vasudeva. (श्रीवासुदेवाष्टकम्)}

नमोऽस्तु नारायण कृष्णचन्द्र\\
नमोऽस्तु नारायण राघवेन्द्र।\\
नमोऽस्तु नारायण मुक्तिहेतो\\
नारायणायैव नमो नमोऽस्तु॥१।१॥\sourceatright{(adapted from~लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् ८०-८१)}


1. O Krishnachandra Narayana, I bow to Thee. O Raghabendra Narayana, I
bow to Thee. O Giver of Moksha, O Narayana I bow only to Thee.


वासुदेवाय वन्द्याय वरदाय वरात्मने।\\
अभय-वर-हस्ताय वराय वररूपिणे॥१।२॥\sourceatright{(लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् २)}


2. I bow repeatedly to Vasudeva, Who is revered by all, Who bestows
boons and Who is Supreme absolute, from Whose hands, boon and safety
from all dangers are obtained by creatures and Who is the embodiment of
all boons.


सर्व्वारिष्ट विनाशाय सर्वसम्पत्-कराय च।\\
सर्वदुःखप्रशान्ताय सर्व्वसौभाग्यदायिने॥१।३॥\sourceatright{(लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् ४६)}


3. I bow to Thee, Who destroys all evils and bestows all that is good
for us, Who relieves us from sorrows and sufferings and gives us good
fortune.


सर्व्वैश्वर्यप्रदात्रे च सर्व्वकार्य्य-विधायिने।\\
सर्व्वज्वरविनाशाय सर्व्वरोगापहारिणे॥१।४॥\sourceatright{(लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् ४८)}


4-5. I bow repeatedly to Thee, Who gives us all wealth, bestows success
to all our works, Who drives all our diseases away, Who kills our
enemies, Rakshasas and ghosts, removes all our obstacles, and drives
away the darkness of ignorance.

शत्रुघ्नाय अविघ्नाय विघ्नकोटि-हराय च।\\
रक्षोघ्नाय तमोघ्नाय भूतघ्नाय नमो नमः॥१।५॥\sourceatright{(लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् ४३)}
अनादिस्त्व-मनन्तस्त्व-मभूतो भूत-विग्रहः।\\
स्तुति-स्तुत्य-स्तवप्रीतः स्तोता नेता नियामकः॥१।६॥\sourceatright{(लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् ९८)}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Language switching isn't automatic. Since you have set the main language to `english` you need to explicitly mark the `sanskrit` parts with `\begin{sanskrit} ... \end{sanskrit}`.  But `polyglossia` requires XeLaTeX not LuaLaTeX for many things including Sanskrit (LuaLaTeX support is limited).

Comment: Can you say why you're trying to compile with LuaTeX rather than XeTeX? (Also, a simple trick if you don't want to keep switching languages is to `\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}`: it ought not to work but in practice it sometimes does.)

Comment: What happens if you load `fontspec` before `polyglossia` and its language settings? I believe this is best practice. Alan's advice is probably best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a XeTeX related error because support for Sanskrit in `polyglossia` requires XeLaTeX and cannot be used with LuaLaTeX.  This is because it uses `\XeTeXintercharclass`, for which there is no current LuaLaTeX equivalent.

Furthermore, language switching between languages is not automatic: you need to markup any non-default language in its own environment or with `\text<language>` for smaller parts.

This requirement extends to the `memoir` formatting commands, which need to be changed to use the `\englishfont`.

Since this document has some regular structure to it, I've also added some macros to make things a bit simpler:

- used the `verse` environment from `memoir`
- added `\begin{sanskrit}` and `\end{sanskrit}` to each `verse` environment
- created a `\newverse` macro to introduce the numbered parts automatically

I've also removed some superfluous lines: `\setmainlanguage{english}` (you only need `\setdefaultlanguage` and `\usepackage{fontspec}` (loaded by `polyglossia`).

Compile with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[text={4.3in,6.95in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguages{sanskrit}
\setmainfont{ITF Devanagari Book}[Script=Devanagari]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont{ITF Devanagari Book}[Script=Devanagari,Ligatures=TeX]
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\englishfont}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\englishfont}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\englishfont}
\newcounter{myverse}
\newcommand\newverse{\stepcounter{myverse}\noindent\themyverse.\quad}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{\begin{sanskrit}}
\AtEndEnvironment{verse}{\end{sanskrit}\par\bigskip}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Hymn to Lord Vasudeva. \textsanskrit{(श्रीवासुदेवाष्टकम्)}}
\begin{verse}
नमोऽस्तु नारायण कृष्णचन्द्र\\
नमोऽस्तु नारायण राघवेन्द्र।\\
नमोऽस्तु नारायण मुक्तिहेतो\\
नारायणायैव नमो नमोऽस्तु॥१।१॥\sourceatright{(\textenglish{adapted from}~लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् ८०-८१)}
\end{verse}

\newverse O Krishnachandra Narayana, I bow to Thee. O Raghabendra Narayana, I
bow to Thee. O Giver of Moksha, O Narayana I bow only to Thee.

\begin{verse}
वासुदेवाय वन्द्याय वरदाय वरात्मने।\\
अभय-वर-हस्ताय वराय वररूपिणे॥१।२॥\sourceatright{(लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् २)}
\end{verse}

\newverse I bow repeatedly to Vasudeva, Who is revered by all, Who bestows
boons and Who is Supreme absolute, from Whose hands, boon and safety
from all dangers are obtained by creatures and Who is the embodiment of
all boons.

\begin{verse}
सर्व्वारिष्ट विनाशाय सर्वसम्पत्-कराय च।\\
सर्वदुःखप्रशान्ताय सर्व्वसौभाग्यदायिने॥१।३॥\sourceatright{(लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् ४६)}
\end{verse}
\end{document}

3. I bow to Thee, Who destroys all evils and bestows all that is good
for us, Who relieves us from sorrows and sufferings and gives us good
fortune.


सर्व्वैश्वर्यप्रदात्रे च सर्व्वकार्य्य-विधायिने।\\
सर्व्वज्वरविनाशाय सर्व्वरोगापहारिणे॥१।४॥\sourceatright{(लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् ४८)}


4-5. I bow repeatedly to Thee, Who gives us all wealth, bestows success
to all our works, Who drives all our diseases away, Who kills our
enemies, Rakshasas and ghosts, removes all our obstacles, and drives
away the darkness of ignorance.

शत्रुघ्नाय अविघ्नाय विघ्नकोटि-हराय च।\\
रक्षोघ्नाय तमोघ्नाय भूतघ्नाय नमो नमः॥१।५॥\sourceatright{(लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् ४३)}
अनादिस्त्व-मनन्तस्त्व-मभूतो भूत-विग्रहः।\\
स्तुति-स्तुत्य-स्तवप्रीतः स्तोता नेता नियामकः॥१।६॥\sourceatright{(लक्ष्मीनरसिंह सहस्रनामस्तोत्रम् ९८)}



\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently working on the `babel` support for “complex scripts” and it's somewhat unstable, but the following preamble with the document body in Alan Munn's post seems to work. Unfortunalety, the default `luatex` font loader is problematic with Indic scripts (many clusters might not be rendered correctly), so very likely you must use `xetex` after all.

```
\documentclass[9pt,a5paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[text={4.3in,6.95in}]{geometry}

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\babelprovide[import=en-GB]{british}
\babelprovide[import=hi]{sanskrit}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontscript{Devanagari}{deva}

\babelfont{rm}{DejaVu Serif}
\babelfont[sanskrit]{rm}{Shobhika}

\babeltags{sanskrit = sanskrit, english = british}

\newcounter{myverse}
\newcommand\newverse{\stepcounter{myverse}\noindent\themyverse.\quad}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{\begin{sanskrit}}
\AtEndEnvironment{verse}{\end{sanskrit}\par\bigskip}
```

**EDIT**. Added `\newfontscript{Devanagari}{deva}`, which seems to be the correct OpenType script in this font (and not `dev2`, selected by default).